# How to slow down file downloads on local ruby webserver?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rack

I'd like to mock large (>100MB) and slow file downloads locally by a ruby service - rails, sinatra, rack or something else.

After starting server and writing something like: http://localhost:3000/large_file.rar, I'd like to slooowly download a file (for testing purposes).

My question is, how to throttle local webserver to certain maximum speed? Because if file is stored locally, it will by default download very fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `curl` for this, which allows you to specify a maximum transfer speed with the `--limit-rate` option. The following would download a file at about 10KB per second:

```
curl --limit-rate 10K http://localhost:3000/large_file.rar
```

From the documentation:

> The given speed is measured in bytes/second, unless a suffix is
>   appended. Appending ‘k’ or ‘K’ will count the number as kilobytes, ‘m’
>   or M’ makes it megabytes, while ‘g’ or ‘G’ makes it gigabytes.
>   Examples: 200K, 3m and 1G.
>
> The given rate is the average speed counted during the entire
>   transfer. It means that curl might use higher transfer speeds in short
>   bursts, but over time it uses no more than the given rate.

More examples here (search for "speed limit"): http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/documentation/curl/index.html

Comment: I'd prefer to throttle server, but this will work too, because I'm using curb gem for download. Thanks!